# How can I check if I have deployed a given OpenAI model in any of my instances within my Azure account?

Tags: azure-openai-service

I have deployed several OpenAI models in several instances in my Azure account. I wonder if I deployed a given OpenAI model (e.g., `gpt-35-turbo-0613-16k`) in one of my instances. How can I check if I have deployed a given OpenAI model in any of my instances within my Azure account? I don't want to check instance one by one.